# What's really happening in this Python encryption script?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, binary, binaryfiles

I'm currently learning to use Python for binary files. I came across this code in the book I'm reading:

```
FILENAME = 'pc_rose_copy.txt'

def display_contents(filename):
    fp = open(filename, 'rb')
    print(fp.read())
    fp.close()

def encrypt(filename):
    fp = open(filename, 'r+b')
    text = fp.read()
    fp.seek(0)
    for c in text:
        if c <= 128:
            fp.write(bytes([c+128]))
        else:
            fp.write(bytes([c-128]))
    fp.close()

display_contents(FILENAME)
encrypt(FILENAME)
display_contents(FILENAME)
```

I've several doubts regarding this code for which I can't find an answer in the book:

1) In line 13 ("if c <= 128"), since the file was opened in binary mode, each character is read as its index in the ASCII table (i.e., that is equivalent to 'if ord(c) <= 128' had the file not been in binary mode)?

2) If so, then what's the point in checking if any character's index is higher than 128, since this is a .txt with a passage from Romeo and Juliet?

3) This point is more of a curiosity, so pardon naivety. I know this doesn't apply in this case, but say the script encounters a 'c' with a byte value of 128, and so adds 128 to it. What would 256 byte look like -- would it be 11111111 00000001?

Comment: On #2: how would Python know that *you* are feeding it a pure ASCII file? If your question is "why would I need to add such a check", then, by all means, remove it.

Comment: All of the answers to this question miss a crucial point which I think is hampering your understanding.  `c`, here, is not a character.  It is a byte.  So for example, if the file contained the character "", then each individual byte that makes up that symbol would be looped through.  I think most emoji are 3/4 bytes.  ASCII is long gone and irrelevant.  Forget about it.  1 character is **not** 1 byte.

Answer (score 2):

What's really happening is that the script is **toggling the most significant bit of every byte.** This is equivalent to adding/subtracting 128 to each byte. You can see this by looking at the file contents before/after running the script (`xxd -b file.txt` on linux or mac will let you see the exact bits/bytes).

Here's a run on some sample text:

**File Contents Before:**

```
11110000 10011111 10011000 10000100 00001010
```

**File Contents After:**

```
01110000 00011111 00011000 00000100 10001010
```

Running the script twice (or any even number of times) restores the original text by toggling all of the high bits back to the original values.

**Question / Answer:**

1) If the file is ASCII-encoded, yes. e.g. for a file `abc\n`, the values of `c` are 97, 98, 99, and 10 (newline). You can verify this by adding `print(c)` inside the loop. This script will also work* on non-ASCII encoded files (the example above is UTF-8).

2) So that we can flip the bits. Even if we were only handling ASCII files (which isn't guaranteed), the bytes we get from *encrypting* ASCII files will be larger than 128, since we've added 128 to each byte. So we still need to handle that case in order to decrypt our own files.

3) As is, the script crashes, because `bytes()` requires values in the range `0 <= x < 256` (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes)). You can create a file that breaks the script with `echo -n -e '\x80\x80\x80' > 128.txt`. The script should be using `<` instead to handle this case properly.

* Except for 3)

Comment: Fixed. I think "first" was hopefully unambiguous for the examples in the post (since it's clear which bit is changing) but MSB/LSB terminology is definitely better if only to avoid endian-related confusion.

Comment: `:)` better. I'd give you an upvote, except that I already did the first time. So here is something else for you: 

Answer (score 1):

I think that the encrypt function is also meant to be a decrypt function.
The encrypt goes from a text file to a binary file with only high bytes. But the else clause is for going back from high byte to text. I think that if you added an extra `encrypt(FILENAME)` you'd get the original file back.

'c' cannot really be 128, in a text file. The highest value there would be 126 (~), 127 is the `del` "character". But c=128 and adding 128 as bytes would be 0 (wrap around) as we work modulo 256. In C this would be the case (for unsigned char).

Comment: Python will happily add 128 to 128 – but at that point, converting back to a character, Python 2 will complain that `chr() arg not in range(256)`. Python 3 (which OP is using) will convert it to `Ā`, the Unicode character `U+0100`, *if* the string is converted to a text string. If it's a `bytearray` object, you get the (expected) error `byte must be in range(0, 256)`.